# Showing the correct menu a page belongs

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-panels, drupal-navigation

I have a **Drupal** website with 3 menus (a top menu, a main menu and a footer menu), and any content I publish belongs to one of those 3. My clients wants me to show the correct menu as an accordion on the sidebar, as a navigational support. I've looked all over drupal modules and can't find anything similar. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. it's called [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block)